# How to change a label inside a loop

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am doing a ipad applicaction, in mi code, I am inside a big loop to synchronize all the data, and I want to change the value of a label, for this I have this

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
        dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
            UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
            myLabel.text = [issue objectForKey:@"title"];
            [self.avisoSync addSubview:myLabel];

        });
```

the problem is,  if I stop the code in this point and move step by step I see the label with the value, but if the code run I don't see anything.

How to change this variable all the time, and see in the view al the changes?

any idea

Comment: You need to elaborate. If this is in a loop, you are not changing any value. You are creating a new `UILabel` over and over again at the same coordinates. Are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 4):

You should never touch a UI object from anything but the main queue. The code you posted doesn't do anything except add a label so I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I'll assume you are doing something else in that block and not showing us for whatever reason. I'd strongly recommend reading the [GCD docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/concurrencyprogrammingguide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) from Apple before throwing code into an app that uses it; while extremely powerful, it makes it quite easy to get yourself into bad situations quickly.

```
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
      // Do some work

      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Only touch the UI from a block enqueued on the main queue
        UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
        myLabel.text = [issue objectForKey:@"title"];
        [self.avisoSync addSubview:myLabel];
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi everyone finally I found the solution to set the value to label and show to the user, I try your solution @RyanR thanks but no work for my.

Inside my loop the user can see a view but the loop is very big and the user don´t see any change for a couple of seconds. so it look like the application was stoping.

So I found and try this and work

```
self.loadInfo.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Create Projects %@",[project objectForKey:@"name"]];
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantPast]];
```

this change the label all the time and the user can see the application is working.